# FileSystemWatcher to monitor Folder download complete

Tags: c++-cli, command-line-interface

I have been playing around with this idea of how to detect that a folder download has been complete using FileSystemWatcher. What I have achieved up to now is that I am able to detect the creation of this folder, and then that triggers a watcher that watches for changes inside this watcher. Whenever a files is created inside this folder, I'll try to access it and check if it's locked or not.

The problem is: How to know that all of the files inside this folder are done being written?

I know I could process each file individually, but how to go from that to an all inclusive result?

I need this because after the folder has been completely written, I would archive it, and upload it to an FTP.

This is the code I have for now:

```
static void OnChanged( Object^ /*source*/, FileSystemEventArgs^ e )
{   

    Console::WriteLine( "File: {0} {1}", e->FullPath, e->ChangeType );

    FileSystemWatcher^ watcher2 = gcnew FileSystemWatcher;
    watcher2->Path = e->FullPath;
    watcher2->NotifyFilter = static_cast<NotifyFilters>( NotifyFilters::LastWrite | NotifyFilters::DirectoryName |NotifyFilters::FileName);
    watcher2->Filter = "*.*";
    watcher2->Changed += gcnew FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged2);
    watcher2->EnableRaisingEvents = true;


}

static void OnChanged2(Object^ /*source*/, FileSystemEventArgs^ e )
{

Console::WriteLine( "Watching started", e->FullPath);

FileInfo^ fileInfo = gcnew FileInfo(e->FullPath);
while(IsFileLocked(fileInfo))
{
    Thread::Sleep(500);
}

}

static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo^ file)
```

{
    FileStream^ stream = nullptr;

```
try
{
    stream = file->Open(System::IO::FileMode::Open, 
        System::IO::FileAccess::ReadWrite, System::IO::FileShare::None);
}
catch (IOException^ ex)
{
    //the file is unavailable because it is:
    //still being written to
    //or being processed by another thread
    //or does not exist (has already been processed)
    return true;
}
finally
{
    if (stream != nullptr)
        stream->Close();
}

//file is not locked
return false;
```

}

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can't, a file system watcher uses a very low-level hook into the file system.  There's no such notification as "a file was closed".  You could only *infer* it by a long absence of change notifications.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve what I'm after? if I want to infer by a long absence of change notifications, does that depend on the rate the data is being written?